# Перенос строки

Tags: php

Вопрос от новичка. В документации пишется что `\r\n` - это указание конца строки и перевода каретки. На деле не работает. Перевожу по `/br`. Что же такое тогда `\n`.

**Добавлено.**

Немного про другое спрашивал. В учебнике явно сказано:

```
<?php
echo "строка1 \n";
echo "строка2";
?>
```

даст

> строка1
> строка2

Но на практике не работает. Пишет в одну строку. Вот я и не понял. В чем подвох.

Comment: Вы путаете HTML и просто текст. HTML не переносит строки по \r, \n или \r\n, а только на основании разметки.

Answer (score 8):

Если у вас весь код на писан для вывода через "\r\n" (Кстати вместо нее лучше использовать `PHP_EOL`, для кроссплатформенности), то есть замечательная функция [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.nl2br.php), которая пройдет по строке, в которую записали весь текст сформированный страницы, и заменит все переводы строк на `<br/>`.

Answer (score 6):

Если вы хотите перенести строки на странице, которая отображается, то используйте `<br/>` помимо этого существует ещё и исходный код. Перенос там осуществляется именно посредством `\n`. Исходный код форматируют для читабельности.

Взгляните на *исходный код* этой *страницы*. Все эти переносы и сделаны посредством `\n` либо обычного нажатия `Enter`.

Этот код на php

```
echo "строка1<br/>";
echo "строка2";
```

даёт нам

```
строка1
строка2
```

на странице и

```
строка1<br/>строка2
```

в самом файле.

В этом и разница. Надеюсь, правильно понял ваш вопрос.

Comment: Да, это я понимаю. Благодарю за ответ. Немного про другое спрашивал.

Comment: Всё. Дошло. БЛАГОДАРЮ ВСЕХ.

Answer (score 4):

`<br />` - это HTML-тег, который говорит браузеру о том, что следующий за ним контент должен выводиться с новой строки.

`\r\n` - обычный перевод строки в тексте. Также есть кросплатформенная константа для перевода строки - `PHP_EOL`.

Переводы строк в тексте браузером игнорируются (кроме нескольких исключительных ситуаций) и их можно увидеть только если открыть HTML-код страницы.

Answer (score 4):

Результат с переводом строки получится при выводе текста в файл или при помещении его в `<pre>` или `textarea`. Если вы хотите вывести текст с переносом на экран, пользуйтесь функцией [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).
Да и вообще, не верьте учебникам на слово. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Про PHP_EOL сказали верно,например этот код:
`<?php
echo "hello",PHP_EOL;
echo "world"
?>`
даст
hello
world

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите: пишу в консоли Clous9:

```
echo "\n";
echo "1: first_srt=1\nsecnd_srt=2\n";
echo "\n";
echo '2: first_srt=1\nsecnd_srt=2\n';
echo "\n";
echo "==============\n";
echo "\n";
```

и получаю:

```
  1: first_srt=1
  secnd_srt=2

  2: first_srt=1\nsecnd_srt=2\n
  ==============
```

Разница строк 1 и 2 - двойные и одинарные кавычки.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно ставить `header` в начало кода

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
echo "раз ...\n";
echo "два ...\n";
echo "три ...\n";
```